# Codeigniter dynamic table with database query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a table for the reporting of some data.
So I have a query in my model called:

```
query($statusId, $regionId);
```

so the value depends on statusID and regionID.

```
___________|____1___|____2____|____3___|

|_____1_____|query(1,1)|query(1,2)|query(1,3)|

|_____2_____|query(2,1)|query(2,2)|query(2,3)|

|_____3_____|query(3,1)|query(3,2)|query(3,3)|
```

But how can I do this? 
Here I write the query into the $data array in the controller. But i dont know how to define the $statusId and $regionId

```
    $num_meas_region= $this->MMeasure->get_measure_number_and_region($statusId, $regionId);
$data["num_meas_region"] = $num_meas_region;
```

Comment: `$statusId = 1;` is how you define the status ID...

Comment: that would be to easy :D I want to give out this query in a loop

Comment: Then you need a double for loop, `i=0; i<=3; i++` and then inside a second using j. Add it to an array